# How to display the first tab using material UI tabs in react?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tabs

**Hello! I use the material UI library in my react project. Everything works, but I have one issue.** **The issue is I can't display the first tab.** So when I open my website all tabs are closed, and only when I click on the link, I see a tab. So how to display the first tab?

**Here is my react component code, which includes those tabs:**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Table from "../assets/img/table.png";
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Tab from '@mui/material/Tab';
import TabContext from '@mui/lab/TabContext';
import TabList from '@mui/lab/TabList';
import TabPanel from '@mui/lab/TabPanel';
import SectionTab from "./SectionTab";
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import {ThemeProvider} from "@mui/material";

function Tabs(props) {

   const tabs = [
       {
           id: 1,
           idInString: "1",
           tabCards: [
               {
                   img: Table,
                   title: 'School desk',
                   price: '1000$',
                   id: 0
               },
               {
                   img: Table,
                   title: 'School desk',
                   price: '1000$',
                   id: 1
               },
               {
                   img: Table,
                   title: 'School desk',
                   price: '1000$',
                   id: 2
               },
               {
                   img: Table,
                   title: 'School desk',
                   price: '1000$',
                   id: 3
               },
               {
                   img: Table,
                   title: 'School desk',
                   price: '1000$',
                   id: 4
               },
               {
                   img: Table,
                   title: 'School desk',
                   price: '1000$',
                   id: 5
               },
           ]
       },

       {
           id: 2,
           idInString: "2",
           tabCards: [
               {
                   img: Table,
                   title: 'Cool table',
                   price: '1000$',
                   id: 0
               },
               {
                   img: Table,
                   title: 'School desk',
                   price: '1000$',
                   id: 1
               },
               {
                   img: Table,
                   title: 'School desk',
                   price: '1000$',
                   id: 2
               },
               {
                   img: Table,
                   title: 'School desk',
                   price: '1000$',
                   id: 3
               },
               {
                   img: Table,
                   title: 'School desk',
                   price: '1000$',
                   id: 4
               },
               {
                   img: Table,
                   title: 'School desk',
                   price: '1000$',
                   id: 5
               },
           ]
       },

       {
           id: 3,
           idInString: "3",
           tabCards: [
               {
                   img: Table,
                   title: 'School desk',
                   price: '1000$',
                   id: 0
               },
               {
                   img: Table,
                   title: 'School desk',
                   price: '1000$',
                   id: 1
               },
               {
                   img: Table,
                   title: 'School desk',
                   price: '1000$',
                   id: 2
               },
               {
                   img: Table,
                   title: 'School desk',
                   price: '1000$',
                   id: 3
               },
               {
                   img: Table,
                   title: 'School desk',
                   price: '1000$',
                   id: 4
               },
               {
                   img: Table,
                   title: 'School desk',
                   price: '1000$',
                   id: 5
               },
           ]
       },

       {
           id: 4,
           idInString: "4",
           tabCards: [
               {
                   img: Table,
                   title: 'School desk',
                   price: '1000$',
                   id: 0
               },
               {
                   img: Table,
                   title: 'School desk',
                   price: '1000$',
                   id: 1
               },
               {
                   img: Table,
                   title: 'School desk',
                   price: '1000$',
                   id: 2
               },
               {
                   img: Table,
                   title: 'School desk',
                   price: '1000$',
                   id: 3
               },
               {
                   img: Table,
                   title: 'School desk',
                   price: '1000$',
                   id: 4
               },
               {
                   img: Table,
                   title: 'School desk',
                   price: '1000$',
                   id: 5
               },
           ]
       },

       {
           id: 5,
           idInString: "5",
           tabCards: [
               {
                   img: Table,
                   title: 'School desk',
                   price: '1000$',
                   id: 0
               },
               {
                   img: Table,
                   title: 'School desk',
                   price: '1000$',
                   id: 1
               },
               {
                   img: Table,
                   title: 'School desk',
                   price: '1000$',
                   id: 2
               },
               {
                   img: Table,
                   title: 'School desk',
                   price: '1000$',
                   id: 3
               },
               {
                   img: Table,
                   title: 'School desk',
                   price: '1000$',
                   id: 4
               },
               {
                   img: Table,
                   title: 'School desk',
                   price: '1000$',
                   id: 5
               },
           ]
       },

   ];

   const links = [
       {
           name: 'Tables',
           id: 0
       },
       {
           name: 'Tables',
           id: 1
       },
       {
           name: 'Tables',
           id: 2
       },
       {
           name: 'Tables',
           id: 3
       },
       {
           name: 'Tables',
           id: 4
       },
   ]

   // #F08C00

   const tabsTheme = createTheme({
       palette: {
           primary: {
               light: '#ffaa36',
               main: '#F08C00',
               dark: '#a05e00',
               contrastText: '#fff',
           },
           secondary: {
               light: 'black',
               main: 'black',
               dark: '#ba000d',
               contrastText: '#000',
           },
       },
   });


   const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

   const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
       setValue(newValue);
   };

   return (
       <div className="tabs-container">
           <h1 className="tabs-title">Products</h1>
           <ThemeProvider theme={tabsTheme}>
               <Box sx={{width: '100%', typography: 'body1', marginTop: '50px'}}>
                   <TabContext value={value}>
                       <Box sx={{borderBottom: 1, borderColor: 'divider', maxWidth: '1200px', margin: '0 auto'}}>
                           <TabList onChange={handleChange}
                                    aria-label="lab API tabs example"
                                    variant="scrollable"
                                    scrollButtons
                                    allowScrollButtonsMobile
                           >
                               <Tab label="Tables & desks" value="1"/>
                               <Tab label="Sofas" value="2"/>
                               <Tab label="Beds" value="3"/>
                               <Tab label="Bookcases & wardrobes" value="4"/>
                               <Tab label="Kitchens" value="5"/>
                           </TabList>
                       </Box>
                       {tabs.map( (tab) =>
                           <TabPanel value={tab.idInString}>
                               <SectionTab key={tab.id} cards={tab.tabCards}/>
                           </TabPanel>
                       )}
                   </TabContext>
               </Box>
           </ThemeProvider>
       </div>
   );
}

export default Tabs;
```

Please, help me to solve this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your state value starts at 0 whereas your Tabs start with the value of 1.

Here's the culprit:

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
```

whereas,

```
<Tab label="Tables & desks" value="1"/>
```

Start value as 1 and you'll see the first tab being selected.